# How do I impute missing values with row mean?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, missing-data

I want to impute the missing values of VPS8 using row mean.

**After considering the comments, the edit is as below:**

```
VPS8 <- data.frame(YAL002W=as.numeric(cdc15["YAL002W",]))
ind <- which(is.na(VPS8), arr.ind=TRUE)
VPS8[ind] <- rowMeans(VPS8, na.rm=TRUE)[ind[,1]]
```

The returned values are:

```
num[1:6] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

[image: Original VPS8 data]

**Desired output**
Impute the missing values with the row mean and save as something.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error, try converting the `VPS8` to a dataframe.
Edit:

```
VPS8 <- data.frame(YAL002W=as.numeric(cdc15["YAL002W",]))
time <- as.numeric(row.names.data.frame(VPS8))
df <- data.frame(VPS8,time)
ind <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
df[ind] <- rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)[ind[,1]]
```

Check if this works

Comment: After I follow your recommendation, the error disappeared. However, `df[ind] <- rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)[ind[,1]]` (my last line of code) gave an error: Error in rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: One of your cols in your `df` dataframe is not in numeric format. That's why the error. You can convert cols to numeric format.

Comment: Can you tell me your desire output? So I can post the answer clearly. You can edit your question and add in desired output.

Comment: When I tried to cast ind as numeric, I get an error `Error in which(is.na(as.numeric(VPS8)), arr.ind = TRUE) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: @mellio Edited the answer. Pl check